# How to use combined if with case when the enum has associated value

Tags: swift, enums

I've got an `enum` like so:

```swift
enum TheType  {
    case a (CustomData)
    case b (NSDictionary)
    case c (String?)
    case d 
    case e
    ...
}
```

In a particular place I just want to check if the type is `b`, however after consulting several tutorials on `if` and `case` and trying several permutations, I still can't get it to compile. Here's the latest variation of my attempts:

```swift
let theType = TheType.b([:])
if case let TheType.b(_) ==  theType {...}
```

Produces the error:

> '_' can only appear in a pattern on the left side of an assignment

Or this produces a different error:

```swift
if case let TheType.b(let theDictionary) == theType {...}
```

Swapping things around so `theType` is on the left of `==` also produces errors.

How can I use an `if` statement to check the type of the `enum` value?

Comment: one simple way is to:

`
enum TheType {
    case b (NSDictionary)
    case c (String?)
    
    var isString: Bool {
      switch self {
      case .b:
        return false
      case .c:
        return true
      }
    }
  }
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`If case let` is **not** just a check for equation, the `==` operator is wrong.

It's either

```
if case let TheType.b(theDictionary) = theType {...}
```

or

```
if case TheType.b(let theDictionary) = theType {...}
```

And if the associated value doesn't matter it's

```
if case TheType.b(_) = theType {...}
```

or even

```
if case TheType.b = theType {...}
```

Note the assignment operator and the different positions of `let`